# space in python subprocess.Popen() arguments

Tags: python, subprocess

I try to invoke an external perl script in my python script. I used `subprocess.Popen()`. If run it like

`subprocess.Popen([mybinary, '-arg1 argv1', '-arg2 argv2'])`

the arguments are not sent to `mybinary`. But if I separate arguments from values, then it runs properly:

`subprocess.Popen([mybinary, '-arg1', 'argv1', '-arg2', 'argv2'])`

Why is it so? args needs to be a string or list. If I concatenate `mybinary` and the arguments into a single string for `Popen()`, `Popen()` does not work, either. I suspect it is relevant to the key-worded arguments (**kwargs). But the script invoked is external. I don't see the reason.

Answer (score 0):

> I try to invoke an external perl script in my python script. I used
>   subprocess.Popen(). If run it like
>
> ```
> subprocess.Popen([mybinary, '-arg1 argv1', '-arg2 argv2'])
> ```
>
> the arguments are not sent to mybinary.

I doubt that. I rather think they come along there in a non-proper way.

The script expects options and their values as two separate arguments. If they are combined, it doesn't work.

The arguments are passed in shape and count exactly as you give them in the list.